# Negative temperature thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature

I asked [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/158142/thermodynamics-internal-energy) about thermodynamics.

I considered $$T=\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}$$ at constant $V$ and $N$ (number of particles), but now I can't figure out the change of $U$ with respect to $V$ if $T<0$. Can somebody help me?

I also thought that $T = \text{slope of the tangent line to the function } U(S)$, but I can't figure out what the curve $U(V)$ is when $T<0$, as required.

*Note: I know the temperature can't be negative, but I want to know what would theoretically happen.*

Comment: More on [negative temperature](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+negative+temperature).